# How to truncate the logs in Promtail

Tags: grafana-loki, promtail

I am using Promtail to ship some Jenkins logs to Loki and I want to truncate the logs which are longer than e.g. 12k characters.
This is the current configuration that I'm using:

```
    clients:
      - url: my-loki-instance
        external_labels:
          cluster: "clustername"
          app: "jenkins-test-promtail"
          namespace: ${JENKINS_NAMESPACE}
          pod: ${JENKINS_POD_NAME}
          container: ${JENKINS_CONTAINER}
          node: ${JENKINS_NODE_NAME}
    positions:
      filename: "/var/log/jenkins/promtail/positions.yaml"
    limits_config:
      readline_rate_enabled: true
      readline_rate_drop: false
    options:
      stream_lag_labels: namespace,pod,container
    scrape_configs:
      - job_name: master_logs
        static_configs:
          - labels:
              component: master
              __path__: /var/log/jenkins/master.0.log
        pipeline_stages:
          - regex:
              expression: "(?P<truncated_log>.{0,12000}).*"
          - output:
              source: truncated_log
```

As expected, most of the logs are shorter than 12k characters and I get this error:

```
level=error ts=2022-10-06T13:48:37.260110981Z caller=main.go:117 msg="error creating promtail" error="failed to make file target manager: invalid regex stage config: could not compile regular expression: error parsing regexp: invalid repeat count: `{0,12000}`"
```

I have tried truncating to smaller values, like 20 characters and it works as expected because the lines are longer than 20 characters.
Any idea how to overcome this or if there's another solution for it?

Promtail version: 2.6.1

**UPDATE**:
I ended up using go templates to do the truncating, like this:

```
...
     pipeline_stages
         - match:
             selector: '{component="master"}'
             stages:
             - template:
                 source: log_truncated
                 template: |
                    {{- if le (len .log) 12000 -}}
                      {{ .log }}
                    {{- end -}}
                    {{- if gt (len .log) 12000 -}}
                      {{ trunc 12000 .log }} TRUNCATED
                    {{- end -}}
             - output:
                 source: log_truncated
...
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just that "12000" is too big a number for the repeat count? The error is saying that it can't compile the regexp, not that lines don't match it (which I think they would anyway).

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Comment: @AntonPatsev I could not figure out what was the problem with the initial regex so I ended up exploring the `template` stage and made it work with the `trunc` function from go templates. Just added an update.